# Load images daily into Android App from site/server/cloud

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, rss

This is a basic beginner question, I am just trying to get on the right path.

What do I need to use to be able to load new images into my app everyday? I simply want to upload them either to my site or somewhere cloud based and every time I add new images to this site/cloud server I want them to be shown in my app (newest image first).

I am self thought and I have only been doing it for a few months, this is my first attempt at a more complex app and I would really appreciate your help. I am using Android Studio.

Thank you!

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html?m=1 may be of interest

Comment: Why the downvotes? He's not asking to write the code for him, just curious about the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database for your site and your app. Actually I use the [Realtime Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). It works very well and the code is easy to learn. You can link your website to your FirebaseDatabase and your Android app too.

The official page: [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)